# Ruby shell script realtime output

Tags: ruby

**script.sh**

```
echo First!
sleep 5
echo Second!
sleep 5
echo Third!
```

**another_script.rb**

```
%x[./script.sh]
```

I want **another_script.rb** to print the output of **script.sh** as it happens. That means printing "First!", waiting five seconds, printing "Second!', waiting 5 seconds, and so on.

I've read through the different ways to run an external script in Ruby, but none seem to do this. How can I fulfill my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always execute this in Ruby:

```
system("sh", "script.sh")
```

Note it's important to specify how to execute this unless you have a proper `#!/bin/sh` header as well as the execute bit enabled.

Comment: The script has a proper shebang. `system "./script.sh"` produces the same results as `%s[./script.sh]`. I'm looking to print the script's output in real time as it happens, not get the script's output as the return value.

Comment: For me, it runs your script and shows the output correctly. Do you mean to capture the script's output and process it with Ruby? If so, you need to use [`popen3`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3).

Comment: Hmm, what version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Ah, got it working. Something was up with my RVM setup. Thanks!